# How to delete firts SELECT on sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to delete only the first ocurrence that I find with my where sentence. I explain it better, I have 4 dates:

```
Alba
Blanca
Carla
Diana
```

I want to delete the last date, "`Diana`", but I delete all and I don't know why... I put my SQL sentence:

```
DELETE FROM tFichajes 
WHERE IdTrabajador IN (SELECT TOP 1 IdTrabajador 
                       FROM tFichajes 
                       WHERE IdTrabajador='XXX' AND 
                             IdCentro='XXX' 
                       ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Hora DESC)
```

Comment: Well, if you run just the SELECT statement from the SQL, what does it return?

Comment: it returns the IdTrabajador only, now I understand the problem, but... how can I solve it? Thanks! :)

Comment: But what are the VALUES?

Comment: Are you working with MS SQL Server?

Comment: ok you understand the problem, but we don't.  Please explain your problem so we can help fix it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2012, and the problem was that if i have only the IdTrabajador the "delete" erase all the lines of that IdTrabajador, and I only want to delete the last line of that IdTrabajador, I mean... I need to return something that makes me able to delete only the last line of this IdTrabajador

Comment: I solve it! I post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616654/297408) contains two almost identical subqueries, which only differ in the output column returned. If SQL Server supported tuple comparisons, you could combine those two subqueries into one like this:

```
DELETE FROM
  tFichajes
WHERE
  IdTrabajador='XXX'
  AND IdCentro='XXX'
  AND (Fecha, Hora) IN (
    SELECT TOP 1
      Fecha, Hora
    FROM
      tFichajes
    WHERE
      IdTrabajador='XXX'
      AND IdCentro='XXX'
    ORDER BY
      Fecha DESC,
      Hora DESC
  )
;
```

But even though SQL Server does not support that syntax, you can still avoid performing the same request twice by using the subquery above as a derived table and joining it to `tFichajes`:

```
DELETE FROM
  f
FROM
  tFichajes AS f
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1
      Fecha, Hora
    FROM
      tFichajes
    WHERE
      IdTrabajador='XXX'
      AND IdCentro='XXX'
    ORDER BY
      Fecha DESC,
      Hora DESC
  ) AS t1 ON f.Fecha = t1.Fecha AND f.Hora = t1.Hora
WHERE
  f.IdTrabajador='XXX'
  f.AND IdCentro='XXX'
;
```

Note, however, that you are still hitting the `tFichajes` table twice here. You can avoid that too! If `Fecha` and `Hora` actually come from the row that you want to delete, you can do simply this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT TOP 1
    Fecha, Hora
  FROM
    tFichajes
  WHERE
    IdTrabajador='XXX'
    AND IdCentro='XXX'
  ORDER BY
    Fecha DESC,
    Hora DESC
)
DELETE FROM
  t1
;
```

Finally, as a side note, please consider getting into the good habit of [always specifying the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) (instead of just `tFichajes` write `dbo.tFichajes` or whatever the correct schema in your case would be), as well as [always ending SQL statements with a semicolon](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons) (`;`).

Answer (score 0):

if you want only 1 record delete in one attempt

and if your Select Query returns only 1 records then 
do something like this

```
DELETE FROM tFichajes 
WHERE IdTrabajador = (SELECT TOP 1 IdTrabajador 
                       FROM tFichajes 
                       WHERE IdTrabajador='XXX' AND 
                             IdCentro='XXX' 
                       ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Hora DESC)
```

Comment: I want to delete the last line of that IdTrabajador, I repeat: the problem was that if i have only the IdTrabajador the "delete" erase all the lines of that IdTrabajador, and I only want to delete the last line of that IdTrabajador, I mean... I need to return something that makes me able to delete only the last line of this IdTrabajador

Comment: Please Explore your Question more Clearly by adding your Tables hierarchy and sample data as well as your output also if possible then add SQLFIDDLE

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, the problem was that I recieve only one field, and I need all the fields to delete te correct line, so I do this:

```
DELETE 
FROM tFichajes 
WHERE IdTrabajador='XXX' 
  AND IdCentro='XXX' 
  AND Fecha IN (SELECT TOP 1 Fecha 
                FROM tFichajes 
                WHERE IdTrabajador='XXX' 
                   AND IdCentro='XXX' 
                ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Hora DESC) 
  AND Hora IN (SELECT TOP 1 Hora 
               FROM tFichajes 
               WHERE IdTrabajador='XXX' 
                 AND IdCentro='XXX' 
               ORDER BY Fecha DESC, Hora DESC)
```